# sqlcmd gives the connection link failure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, sqlcmd

I am trying to join two tables on azure sql db from my local ubuntu machine. One of the tables has around 300M entries, so it will take some time to run a query. But whenever I run the query like this,

```
sqlcmd -S *server* -d *DB* -U *User* -P *Password*
       -l 600 -t 600 -Q *Query* -s ',' -o *output_file*
       -W -w 1000 -C -M
```

It gives the same error at different points whenever I run it.

This is the error I am getting,

> Sqlcmd: Error: Internal error at ReadAndHandleColumnData (Reason: Error reading column data).
>   SSL Provider: [error:80001044:lib(128):func(1):internal error:unexpected error]
>   Communication link failure

At first, I thought it's a timeout issue, so I increased query timeout and server timeout to 10 minutes. But it doesn't wait for 10 minutes, it throws the error before that. Can someone help please?

Comment: What is the query that you used ?

Comment: select t1.d1, t1.d2, t1.d3, t2.d1 from t1 inner join t2 on t1.d1=t2.d2, not sure if that's the bottleneck.

Comment: Not sure if these are real columns or not, but shouldn't you be joining on `d1` column?

Comment: what happens if you run this query in SSMS ?

Comment: These are not real, I just posted sample query. To answer @GuidoG, I am not sure I can launch SSMS on ubuntu machine.

Comment: Is there another way to test your query on the database just to check if there is a problem with the query or with your connection or with the sqlcmd parameters

Comment: @GuidoG I don't think query is problematic. What's happening is the query is returning output, 1000s of entries are getting written in output file and then it gives the mentioned error. And the point at which it gives the error is changing every time, so it's not because of some random entries which are giving issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error message, but when I ran the query a second time, it worked...

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Seems to be an internal SQL Server/`sqlcmd` issue over which users have very little control.